# Adding outer image to circular image view

Tags: java, android, image, imageview, frame

I have a circular image:

> ```
>     <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
>         android:id="@+id/circularIcon"
>         android:layout_width="100dp"
>         android:layout_height="100dp"
>         android:src="@drawable/img_gr"
>         app:civ_border_color="#EEEEEE"
>         app:civ_border_width="1dp"
>         app:civ_shadow="true"
>         app:civ_shadow_radius="3"
>         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>         app:civ_shadow_color="#8C0F0F"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:visibility="visible"/>
> ```

And I want to add around it, something like a "frame":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uadIp.png

so the frame would be exactly wrapping the circular image view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a simple frame to your circular ImageView you can use this library [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

[image]